# How to find the filename without the extension through JQuery

Tags: filenames

I am hoping to find only the filename within the current page URL.

So if the URL is

```
www.ex.com/des/filename.php
```

or

```
www.ex.com/des/filename.php#9
```

I need to get only

```
filename
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
var loc = window.location;
var fileNameIndex = loc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var output = loc.substr(0, loc.lastIndexOf('.')) || loc;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var loc = window.location.href
var fileNameIndex = loc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var dotIndex = loc.lastIndexOf('.');

var output = loc.substr(fileNameIndex, dotIndex < fileNameIndex ? loc.length : dotIndex);
```

For an explanation of the code: What it does is, it takes the text between the last "/" and the last ".", provided the "." occurs after the "/", otherwise it just takes everything from the last "/" to the end of the string.

Answer (score 9):

```
var loc = window.location.href;
var output  = loc.split('/').pop().split('.').shift()
```